# How to login with python requests: a tricky case

Tags: python-requests

I am trying to access to a website provided by my school, in order to automate the process of checking if a something has been published (such as marks, news, etc.).

I analized the page's html code and searched for all the input tags (even hidden tags) and put them in a dictionary. I wrote this code:

```
import requests, lxml.html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

login_url = "https://www.portaleargo.it/argoweb/famiglia/common/login_form2.jsp"
whenloggedin_url = "https://www.portaleargo.it/argoweb/famiglia/index.jsf#"

def try_conn(sch_code, user, password):

with requests.Session() as s:

    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36'}
    site = s.get(login_url, headers = headers)
    bs_content = bs(site.content, "html.parser")
    token = bs_content.find("input", {"id":"cod_utente"})["value"]
    login_data = {
        "codice_scuola":sch_code,
        "utente":user,
        "j_password":password,
        "cod_utente":token,
    }

    login = s.post(login_url, data = login_data)

    #Proof that it logged in correctly

    if login.url == whenloggedin_url:

        return True

    return False
```

The function returns False. I also tried to print login.status_code (and it returns 200). I really cannot say why this is not working. What should I do?

Comment: What does print(login.url) show?

Comment: @jtlz2 It shows: https://www.portaleargo.it/argoweb/famiglia/common/login_form2.jsp

Comment: and print(whenloggedin_url)?

Comment: it shows: https://www.portaleargo.it/argoweb/famiglia/index.jsf#

Comment: So how can `login.url == whenloggedin_url` be `True`?

Comment: Login is supposed to do a post request to the login page (https://www.portaleargo.it/argoweb/famiglia/common/login_form2.jsp). After the post request I should be able to enter to the "whenloggedin_url". At least, I think that it would work. Am I right or not?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```py
import requests

post_url= "https://www.portaleargo.it/argoweb/famiglia/common/j_security_check"
login_url = "https://www.portaleargo.it/argoweb/famiglia/common/login_form2.jsp"
whenloggedin_url = "https://www.portaleargo.it/argoweb/famiglia/index.jsf#"

def try_conn(sch_code, user, password):

    with requests.Session() as s:

        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36'}
        site = s.get(login_url, headers = headers)
        login_data = {
            "udente":user,
            "j_password":password,
            "j_username":user+"#"+sch_code,
            "submit":"Entra",
        }

        login = s.post(post_url, data = login_data)

        #Proof that it logged in correctly

        if login.url == whenloggedin_url:

            return True

        return False
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is still not working. It keeps returning False and the url doesn't change.

Comment: It is https://www.portaleargo.it/argoweb/famiglia/common/j_security_check. It also prints 400 as status_code.

Comment: I tried the code above, but it didn't work: the status_code is still 400 and it returns False.